# NGINX How to rewrite subdomain to subdirectory if it regex?

Tags: nginx

Hi need to create rewrite:

Expected results:

FOR REQUEST: **sub4.sub3.example.com**

LOAD:        **sub4.example.com/sub3**

I tried this:

```
 server{ 
    listen  80 default_server;
    server_name     ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.test\.server$;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://test.server/$subdomain/$request_uri permanent;
    }
  }
```

But it not work as suspect with recursive redirects.
Any work around?

**UPD:**

```
server{ 
listen  80;
server_name domain.test.server test.server;
root  /usr/share/nginx/html; 

location / {
              if ($host ~* ^(?<sub>.+)*\.test\.server$ )
                 { rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://test.server/$sub/$1; }
           }
   }

}
```

**THIS WORKS BUT WITH REDIRECT:**

```
  curl -I http://domain.test.server/
  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
  Server: nginx/1.12.2
  Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 10:17:52 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 161
  Connection: keep-alive
  Location: http://test.server/domain/
```

Is there some way without redirect?

Comment: Expected results:

Answer (score 0):

```
server{ 
listen  80;
server_name ~^(?<lev4>.+)*\.(?<lev3>.+)*\.(?<lev2>.+)*\.(?<lev1>.+)*$ ; 

root  /var/www/app;

location / {
                   proxy_set_header Host $lev4.$lev2.$lev1 ;
                   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;

                   if ($host ~* ^(?<lev4>.+)*\.(?<lev3>.+)*\.(?<lev2>.+)*\.(?<lev1>.+)*$ ) {
                   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$lev3/$1 break;              
                   }
            }
   }

server{
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
server_name sub4.example.com;

root  /var/www/app;

location / {
           }
   }
```